# WHERE, AND in Cypher query

Tags: apache-age, opencypher

While using the `WHERE` clause in cypher queries how do one join multiple conditions?. Is it valid to use `AND` as in `WHERE condition1 AND condition2` or what’s the valid way to do something of such?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's precisely that way. You can use your condition inside the vertex/edge too, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n:Vertex {property: 'value'})-[e {property: 'value'}]->(v)
    RETURN (v)
$$) as (v agtype);
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n:Vertex)-[e]->(v)
    WHERE n.property = 'value' AND e.property = 'value'
    RETURN (v)
$$) as (v agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use `AND` to join conditions. Other boolean operators are also available such as:

- `OR`: True when either or both conditions are true
- `XOR`: True when either but not both conditions are true
- `NOT`: True when the condition is false

[This Neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/) about the `WHERE` clause contains a whole lot of useful information that should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AND, OR, NOT inside your WHERE section. Such as:

```
SELECT t.name, t.age
FROM schema_name.sql_person as t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
      MATCH (v:Person)
        RETURN v.name, v.age
    $$) as (name agtype, age agtype)
    WHERE name = t.name AND age = t.age
);
```

You can follow [official docs](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/advanced/advanced.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is valid to use  AND and OR statements in WHERE clause to join the condition. The valid syntax is as follows:

```
    MATCH (node)
WHERE condition1 AND condition2
RETURN node
```

If you want to know if either of the condition is true for nodes. Use this:

```
MATCH (node)
WHERE condition1 OR condition2
RETURN node
```

You can also combine the statements:

```
MATCH (node)
WHERE (condition1 AND condition2) OR condition3
RETURN node
```

Answer (score 0):

Age is an extension that provides you with a query joining method.

You can join the statements using AND operator, where every statement will be joined using an AND operator.

For example you have a student and you want to retrieve a student with a certain age and major. You can write query for above statement like as under:

```
MATCH (n:Student)
WHERE n.age > 25 AND n.major = 'Computer Science'
RETURN n
```

This is how joining different statements in apache age work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's valid. You can also use other operators such as:

```
IS NULL: Checks if a property or expression is null.
IS NOT NULL: Checks if a property or expression is not null.
IN: Checks if a property or expression matches any value in a given list.
NOT IN: Checks if a property or expression does not match any value in a given list.
STARTS WITH: Checks if a string property or expression starts with a specified substring.
```

Please read: [WHERE Cypher](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create compound expressions by using AND and OR in WHERE clause. AND had priority over OR and () have priority over both.

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE (n.property1 = 'value1' OR n.property2 = 'value2') AND n.property3 = 'value3'
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid to use `AND` and `WHERE` clause of a Cypher query to join multiple conditions Like:

```
MATCH (n: Person ) WHERE n.age < 30 AND n.name = 'Peter' RETURN n.name, n.age
```

This will return the name and age values for Peter because he is less than 30 years age and his name is Peter.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to use AND in WHERE clause, along with AND you can also use other boolean variables.